# how to load a webview as a row in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-webview

I use custom adapter to load different layout for one of the ListView row. The custom layout that i use contains a Webview. But when i inflate it and check the height and width of the webview , it comes out to be zero, also the webview is not visible in the Listview either.
Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong ?
MyCustomListAdapter getView function is as follows

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (v == null) {
        // Inflate the layout according to the view type
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (type == 0) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_web, parent, false);
            WebView wv = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview1);
            String html="<html><body>Hello World</body></html>";
            wv.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
            System.out.println(wv.getWidth());
            System.out.println(wv.getHeight());              
        } else {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_default, parent, false);
            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            title.setText("Title");
            desc.setText("Description");
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

My list_row_web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/co.silverpush.app_native_ads_silverpush"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

        <WebView
              android:id="@+id/webView1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:layerType="software" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

I would like to mention, that i am actually making an HTTP POST request first and then loading the response that i get from the server into my webview. 
The hardcoded HTML string works , but in case of the request method,i do have the HTML String that i load into the webview using the loadurl() function, but nothing comes up , the row simply wont show up.

Comment: can you put full code?

Comment: It's not a good practice to load elements with scroll one inside another. To obtain a decent performance you will need to disable scrolling in your webviews or in the listview itself.

Comment: @MoradiyaAkash i hope i have given you the exact code that needs attention.

Comment: @LucianoRodríguez i understand your concerns for performance , but that still doesnt answer my question as to why webview wont be working inside the layout_row_web . I will definitely tweak my code address the issue that you just pointed out.

Comment: I know my comment doesn't answer your question. Because of that, it's a comment and not an answer =). Depending on your needs you could try to load your HTML content into a TextView using: textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(HTML_CONTENT));

Comment: @LucianoRodríguez i want the HTML code to be rendered , not just be visible as text(i.e what if i have a img tag in the HTML code) , so no textview is not what i want.btw thanks for the prompt reply =)

Answer (score 1):

You are recycling your row in a bad way. Use something like this:

LISTITEM_ROW.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/visualizer_background"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >

...

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/newsListContent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:layerType="software"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/newsListTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/newsListImage" />

...

</RelativeLayout>
```

You adapter:

```
public class FragmentNewsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

private final ArrayList<RadioMarcaNew> noticias;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
private Activity act;

public FragmentNewsListAdapter(Activity act, ArrayList<RadioMarcaNew> d){

    this.act=act;
    this.noticias = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    if(act!=null) {

        final NewsViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_news, null);
            holder = new NewsViewHolder();

            ...
            holder.content = (WebView) vi.findViewById(R.id.newsListContent);
            ...

            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else holder = (NewsViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        final RadioMarcaNew noticia = noticias.get(position);

        ...
        if(noticia.getHTMLContent()!=null && noticia.getHTMLContent().length()>0) {

            holder.content.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            holder.content.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,cadenaHTML, "text/html","utf-8", null);
            holder.content.setBackgroundColor(act.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
            holder.content.setEnabled(false);
        }
        ...

    }
    return vi;
}

class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {

        super.onLoadResource(view, url);

    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return this.noticias.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}
}

class NewsViewHolder {

    ...
    public WebView content;
    ...
}
```

Finally you should change your listview height to match_parent =)

Comment: Still getting nothing in the row, and height and width are equal to 0

Comment: height and width of what? the webview? can you post please list_row_web?

Comment: yes , thats what i gave in my code , check it above System.out.println(wv.getWidth());
System.out.println(wv.getHeight());

Comment: i don't see the contents of your layout file anywhere, only of your getView method

Comment: If you have the HTML code inside a String you shouldn't call the loadUrl method. You should call holder.content.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,htmlString, "text/html","utf-8", null);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64488/discussion-between-radix-and-luciano-rodriguez).

Answer (score 0):

You inflate a new XML in **each** row, which will be bad for performance. Its better to use a `static holder` with single `XML`. You just need to **hide/show** the `textview`/`webview` according to `type` variable.

If you insist to use your code, try to remove this `if` :

```
if (v == null)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as in how you plan to do it.
i want to just change a row in the Listview with a custom layout.
And i removed the if statement , no change in the current situation.